# Laravel Livewire Pagination links not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I create livewire component WithPagination
Links render correct, but even wire:click="gotoPage(2)" not working properly

```
/** app/Http/Livewire/Project/Index.php **/

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Project;

use App\Models\Project;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Index extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.project.index', [
            'projects' => Project::where('owner_id', Auth::id())->paginate(10)
        ]);
    }
}
```

and view

```
resources/views/livewire/project/index.blade.php

@forelse($projects as $project)
        @if($loop->first)
            <table class="min-w-full">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="px-6 py-3 border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">ID</th>
                    <th class="px-6 py-3 border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Title</th>
                    <th class="px-6 py-3 border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Description</th>
                    <th class="px-6 py-3 border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50 text-left text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Owner</th>
                    <th class="px-6 py-3 border-b border-gray-200 bg-gray-50"></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
    
                <tbody class="bg-white">
        @endif
                    <tr>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">
                            {{ $project->id }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">
                            {{ $project->title }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">
                            {{ $project->description }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200">
                            <div class="flex items-center">
                                <div class="flex-shrink-0 h-10 w-10">
                                    <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name={{ $project->owner->name }}&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="ml-4">
                                    <div class="text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-900">{{ $project->owner->name }}</div>
                                    <div class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">{{ $project->owner->email }}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-right border-b border-gray-200 text-sm leading-5 font-medium">
                            <a href="{{$project->path()}}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">{{__('View')}}</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
        @if($loop->last)
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {{ $projects->links() }}
        @endif
    @empty
        <h3>No projects yet.</h3>
    @endforelse
```

Video:

https://monosnap.com/file/MO59IoLOCoc93tAbU7ET5IlVAVIHWN

In other components events like wire:submit.prevent="createProject" or wire:click="editProject({{ $project->id }})" working correct

Stack:

- PHP 7.4
- Laravel 8
- Livewire 2
- Chrome 85.0.4183.102

Comment: Why `{{ $projects->links() }}` this in foreach? if your projects empty, links will not show.

Comment: outside forelse() it not working too =(

Comment: If I surround table with <div class="container"> </div> all work fine

Comment: And problem was here
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#render-method

Comment: @alexsnowb I have the same issue. Also I get a huge icon "<". Have you figured out the answer?

Comment: @No One, can you show your code? I think you have problem with css or something

Comment: @alexsnowb Thank you for your response. Yes, you are right. I had a problem with the css. I installed bootstrap for the livewire pagination. Now it's working. I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EATD5sFKCzc

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and i solved it just by wrapping all the content of the view in a single div, like this.

```
<div> All your content </div>
```

Comment: Any technical reason for this Hector Andres Rubio?

Comment: In the livewire documentation says: **Livewire components MUST have a single root element. and put this example **  `<div>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>`

Answer (score 4):

you need to Add first

1- in your controller after {use WithPagination}

```
protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
```

2- in your view

```
$projects->links('pagination::bootstrap-4')
```

Comment: Thanks!  I dont think `$users->links('pagination::bootstrap-4')` is documented anywhere!

Answer (score 3):

Livewire Documentation says:

*"Let's say you have a show-posts component, but you want to limit the results to **10** posts per page.
You can paginate the results by using the WithPagination trait provided by Livewire."*

**Component Controller**: App\Http\Livewire\PathToYourComponent\Component:

```
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class ShowPosts extends Component
{
   use WithPagination;

   public function render()
   {
    return view('livewire.show-posts', [
        'posts' => Post::paginate(10),
    ]);
   }
}
```

**Component View:** resources\views\livewire\path-to-your-component\component-view:

```
<div>
 @foreach ($posts as $post)
    ...
 @endforeach

 {{ $posts->links() }}
</div>
```

**Livewire components MUST have a SINGLE ROOT element*

Your **Laravel Blade** result:

```
<html>
 <head>
  ...
  @livewireStyles
  ...
 </head>
 <body>
  Your html body here
   ...
   @livewire('your-component')
   ...
  @livewireScripts
 </body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help other people

Ref: [Livewire Pagination](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/pagination)

Answer (score 0):

you must have a single html container.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just should all your blade content inside  tags.. like this

```
<div> ----> this one
@section("header") 
    @include("layouts.v1.app_admin_header")
    @include("partials.v1.title",[
            "first_title"=>"Listado",
            "second_title"=>"de equipos"
        ])

@endsection


@include("partials.v1.table_nav",
           ["nav_options"=>[
                      ["button_align"=>"right",
                      "click_action"=>"",
                      "button_content"=>"Crear nuevo",
                      "icon"=>"fa-solid fa-plus",
                      "target_route"=>"administrar.equipos.agregar",
                      ],

                  ]
          ])


</div> ----> this one
```

you can have anything, always inside div tags.

In that way livewire has one root component and all works perfectly