# Livewire pagination links display normally but do not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm new to Livewire, and I'm testing my knowledge on it. For example, the pagination links are usually displayed but don't work. I don't understand why yet.

**Personnels.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Personnels extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.personnels.personnels', [
            'users' =>
                User::paginate(3),
        ])
            ->extends('layouts.mastery')
            ->section('contenu');

        Carbon::setLocale('fr');
    }
}
```

**personnels.blade.php**

```
<div class="card-footer">
       {{ $users->links() }}
</div>
```

here is the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4qxz.png)

Comment: Can you post the rendered html of `{{ $users->links() }}`?

Comment: @cerlin the code is too long 4 comments

Comment: Have you published or modified your pagination views?

Comment: @Qirel i modified the css file i just change the color

Comment: You can put it as part of the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66714938/15770919 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do a foreach on your Personnels component.

Livewire needs to track each components, so you need to add a **unique key** to them.

For example:

```
<div class="card-footer" wire:key="$users->id">
       {{ $users->links() }}
</div>
```

Related documentation [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#dom-diffing-cures)

Comment: hi i try it but it does not work ..

Comment: Did you find the solution? I had issue last time using `@livewire('personnels')` instead of `<livewire:personnels />` try it, maybe it will solve